# Angular JS Unit Testing (Karma Jasmine)

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

**This is my service**

```
angular.module('providers',)
    .provider('sample', function(){

        this.getName = function(){
            return 'name';
        };
        this.$get = function($http, $log, $q, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
            this.getTest = function(){
                return 'test';
            };
        };
    });
```

**This is my unit test**

```
describe('ProvideTest', function() 
{
    beforeEach(module("providers"));
    beforeEach(function(){
      module(function(sampleProvider){
        sampleProviderObj=sampleProvider;
      });
    });
    beforeEach(inject());

     it('Should call Name', function()
    {
        expect(sampleProviderObj.getName()).toBe('name');   
    });

    it('Should call test', function()
    {
        expect(sampleProviderObj.getTest()).toBe('test');

    });


});
```

I am getting an error Type Error: 'undefined' is not a function evaluating sampleProviderObj.getTest()

I need a way to access function inside this.$get . Please help

Answer (score 1):

You should inject your service into the test. Replace this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module(function(sampleProvider){
    sampleProviderObj=sampleProvider;
  });
});
beforeEach(inject());
```

With this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_sampleProvider_) {
    sampleProvider = _sampleProvider_;
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need, as had already been said, inject service, that you test. Like following

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($injector) {
    sampleProviderObj = $injector.get('sample');
}));
```

Second, and **more important thing**. Sample have no any getTest functions. If you really need to test this function, you should as "Arrange" part of your test execute also `$get` function of your provider. And then test `getTest` function of result of previous execution. Like this:

```
it('Should call test', function()
{
    var nestedObj = sampleProviderObj.$get(/*provide correct parameters for this function*/)
    expect(nestedObj.getTest()).toBe('test');
});
```

But it's not good because this test can fail even if `nestedObj.getTest` work properly (in case when `sampleProviderObj.$get` works incorrect).

And one more thing, it seems like you need to inject this services `$http`, `$log`, `$q`, `$localStorage`, `$sessionStorage` to you provider rather then passing them as parameters.